# navController for first launch view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I currently have a launch screen storyboard with an image set up as my loading screen.

I'm used to doing everything programmatically, and storyboarding is throwing me for a ride. I have a boolean set up to determine if this is the first time the app is being launched. If so, I want to have one view controller that I set as the root of my navigation controller. If it isn't the first launch, I want to set a different root view controller to my nav controller.

I've clicked and dragged a navigation controller onto my storyboard. I just don't know what to do with it now. I have a viewController set up with an image that I'd like to be the first thing seen if it is the first time the app is being launched. However, I'm not sure what is automatically initialized using storyboard, so conceptually I'm not sure how to set up my app.

Since I have to handle this condition programmatically, **do I even need to create a nav controller in storyboard, or would that be redundant?**

My parent VC (viewController) is just an image with a label overlaid on top. Building with the below code in my appDelegate.h file correctly shows my launch screen storyboard, but then fades to a black screen.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    firstLaunch = YES;

    if (firstLaunch == YES) {

        ViewController *launchScreen = [ViewController new];

        UINavigationController * navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:launchScreen];

        self.window.rootViewController = navControl;

        firstLaunch = NO;
    }

    else {
//        create instance of other view controller and set as root of navigation controller
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas as to why my app is just navigating to a black screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults to present window only on first launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456329/nsuserdefaults-to-present-window-only-on-first-launch)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use

```
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I usually do this in my application like so:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In addition, your code will always say it's the user's first time. I would recommend using NSUserDefaults as such:

```
BOOL hasLaunchedBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedBefore"];
if (!hasLaunchedBefore) {
    //All your first launch UI stuff
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedBefore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else {
    //Not first launch
}
```

Comment: wouldn't I be setting the root view controller of my window to be my nav controller?

Comment: This is a duplicate question and duplicate answer. Please use proper SO etiquette for the users before you that spent the time to give an answer and give them credit due

Comment: @soulshined I'm a bit confused. This was an original answer written by me... Maybe I'm missing something in the etiquette. Sorry, I didn't realize I was doing anything wrong. Let me know what I can do to not break terms in the future?

Comment: Just simply mark a question as duplicate and provide a link to the question or point them to a resource that's already on SO. Nothing wrong with your answer, it's just the fact that so many people have asked this and the OP has show no effort in finding those

Comment: @karansatia you would be. I thought that's what you wanted. If not, then make a root view controller and add your nav controller as a child view controller of that.

Comment: @soulshined gotcha, just didn't realize it was part of my duty to check for previous answers. Will do in the future. Appreciate it. Should i post those links as comments or answers?

Comment: When you flag a question as duplicate. it will automatically notify moderators or the SO gods in for the form of a comment.  And FYI it's everyone's duty, regardless of reputation 1 or 1000. Creates a clutter free community easier to find questions

Comment: @soulshined apologies. I'll make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: @karansatia can you mark as correct when you can? Thanks